# How to specify countries/region while creating maps in R?

Tags: r, maps, ggplot2

map("usa") by default displays a map without Alaska and Hawaii.  map("world") has Antartica by default.  Is there any way to say "include alaska", "exclude antartica" etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
nams <- map("world", namesonly=TRUE, plot=FALSE)

map("world", region=nams[-grep("Antarctica", nams)])
```

Longer answer:

The maps data in "world" is referenced by region names and these are generally character data in "continent:country" or "continent:subregion" format. To get those names which are in an external database, you need to first use maps("world" , ...) with parameters that return only the names and not all of hte other coordinates. If you want to find all the "Antarctica" containing entries you need to use grep() to identify their position in the returned names vector.

Comment: that worked, thanks. I wish there was some good book, for R beginners.  The software is awesome, but the syntax isn't friendly  :(

Comment: I cannot claim to have known all of that in advance. There is a lot of value to be gained by running the examples on the help pages. I did need to look at the help file and do a bit of experimentation to get there. In particular it seemed that needing to include plot=FALSE was necessary to get output as a character vector, but it turned out that those values were being return but only invisibly, so typing `map("world", namesonly=TRUE)` returned nothing at the console but would have succeeded with `nams2 <- map("world", namesonly=TRUE)`.

Comment: This throws me an error: 'regular expression is too large'

Comment: I now also get an error:  "invalid regular expression"  as well as the the 'regular expression is too large' which is only a warning.

Comment: Depending on your goals you can get the same result with `map( "world", ylim=c(-60,90) )`

Answer (score 4):

If you looking just for those areas, the brutal solution would be to use world map, specify USA as a `region` and define latitude/longitude to create limits, so the map will only display specific area:

```
library(maps)
long <- c(-180,-50)
lat <- c(10,80)
map("world",regions=".*usa",xlim=long,ylim=lat)
```

[image]